# How to perform terraform provisioning for other accounts using assumed role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to provision terraform instance in Account A and from account A  to account B.

1)Created a role in account A (arn - arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXX:role/stg-tf-devops-ec2_role to assume role in account B and also have fullEC2 access to provision instance in account A

2)Created a role in account B (arn - arn:aws:iam::YYYYYYY:role/TF_Automation_DevOps) and added ec2 privilege in that role and edited the trust policy and added the role arn created in account A

In account A - I have an instance which i'm using for terraform execution is attached to that stg-tf-devops-ec2_role

Now from my understanding this instance should take care of provisioning instances in both account A and account B without access and secret key.But unfortunately i'm getting below error

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
    }
  }

}

provider "aws" {
  region = var.region
}

provider "aws" {
  region = var.region
  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::YYYYYYYYY:role/TF_Automation_DevOps"
  }
  alias = "dim"
}
```

Error message when executing terraform plan is as below

```
terraform plan
╷
│ Error: error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: IAM Role (arn:aws:iam::YYYYYYYYYY:role/TF_Automation_DevOps) cannot be assumed.
│
│ There are a number of possible causes of this - the most common are:
│   * The credentials used in order to assume the role are invalid
│   * The credentials do not have appropriate permission to assume the role
│   * The role ARN is not valid
│
│ Error: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
│       For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
│
│
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"].dim,
│   on main.tf line 17, in provider "aws":
│   17: provider "aws" {
```

Could you please advice how to proceed further or what went wrong and how to debug further?

As requested in comments,here i'm able to use aws cli without access key and secret key and fetch details from account A

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --region eu-west-2|head -10
{
    "Reservations": [
        {
            "Groups": [],
            "Instances": [
                {
                    "AmiLaunchIndex": 0,
                    "ImageId": "ami-0aac9d7fa83beb6d2",
                    "InstanceId": "i-0d13491bfd0af559e",
                    "InstanceType": "t3.medium",
```

Got the below error when checking whether able to assume the role on account b

```
$ aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::YYYYYYYYYYY:role/TF_Automation_DevOp" --role-session-name "access_chk"
    An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:sts::YYYYYYYYYYY:assumed-role/stg-tf-devops-ec2_role/i-066506ec0993d0148 is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::YYYYYYYYYYY:role/TF_Automation_DevOp
```

Trusted policy in account B as below

```
    {​​​​​​​
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {​​​​​​​
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {​​​​​​​
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXX:role/stg-tf-devops-ec2_role"
      }​​​​​​​,
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }​​​​​​​
  ]
}​​​​​​​
```

Role on account A is having below privileges

[image]

Comment: Does the user / role running the `terraform plan` have permission to assume that automation role? What is the trust policy of the role in account B and what are the specific permissions of the role in Account A? Can you SSH into the instance that runs the terraform snippet and try to use e.g. the `aws cli` to perform a manual assume-role.

Comment: @luk2302 Does the user / role running the terraform plan have permission to assume that automation role? - how to verify this?

Comment: I have edited question and pasted the output which i can able to execute aws cli cmds

Comment: You need to run `aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::YYYYYYY:role/TF_Automation_DevOp" --role-session-name "something"` - if that works you have permission, if it does not work your permissions are not properly set up.

Comment: @luk2302 getting error and pasted the result in question

Comment: As written in my first comment: "What is the trust policy of the role in account B and what are the specific permissions of the role in Account A?"

Comment: @luk2302 updated question with trusted policy.Will update role privs soon

Comment: @luk2302 updated the question with what privileges the role in account  is having

Comment: You need to attach or create and attach a policy that allows the account to assume the role in the other account.

Comment: @luk2302 can you paste this a answer.It worked.I wan to give upvote for you